# Hacer click en button y direccionar a una dirección en específico sin usar html

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo el siguiente botón:

```
<button  type="cancel" class="buttonRed" id="cancelar" >
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cancelar
</button>
```

De por si no tiene un href o dirección asignada para cuando se le da click, quiero asignarle que al darle click se dirija a una página en específico, pero por javascript, no por html.

**EDIT1:** Me ha funcionado perfectamente el `location.href`, sin embargo me gustaria saber si existe diferencia entre usar `location.href` y `window.location.href`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque como te dice @NEA, lo ideal sería que uses una etiqueta `<a>`.

Lo puedes lograr de la siguiente forma:

```
<button type="cancel" class="buttonRed" id="cancelar">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cancelar
</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('cancelar').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    window.location.href='https://www.google.com';
});
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Existe diferencia entre usar `location.href` y `window.location.href`?

Comment: Es lo mismo. Con windows.location te aseguras de estar llamando al la variable global y no a una variable definida en otro lado.

Answer (score 2):

Solo tienes que crear una función [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) y llamarla mediante el evento onclick del botón.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function rdir() {
            location.href="http://www.google.com/";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="has click" onclick="rdir()">
</body>
</html>
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#enlace{
background-color: red;
text-decoration:none;
color: white;
padding: 9px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="###" id=enlace>simulación botón</a>
```

Hombre, ya se que dices que no quieres html, pero porque no haces en vez de un botón, un enlace  con aspecto de botón? Y así te hace la función perfecta sin complicarse?

Adjunto un ejemplo muy simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

Es cierto que la mayor de las veces la etiqueta  es la más apropiada.
Sin embargo en algunos casos el uso de (window.location.href = 'pagina.html'), nos puede ser muy útil.
Hace poco tuve un problema y me tardé en encontrar la respuesta. Es por ello que comunidades como esta resultan muy útiles.

También puedes agregar parámetros:
window.location.href='pagina.html?'+variable;
lo metes en una función y agregas en un manejador de eventos al evento click del botón que desees.